# Intercept any network activity on the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to get notifications in Javascript whenever current web page causes new network requests? And to modify those requests by canceling them and by substituting their response?

In the first place I want to catch image requests caused by elements inside the DOM. XHR requests are in focus too but they seem to be an easier problem.

Thank you!

Comment: How about just load the correct images in the first place...

Comment: You could intercept and modify the request in an extension. Would that be an option? If so, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications, http-on-modify-request and http-on-examine-response for Firefox. For Chrome, check out chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Service Workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/) to the rescue.

Comment: Thanks! But as of today a lot of browsers don't support them, right?

Comment: @Andrej that is true, but Service Workers are the only way to accomplish what you want to do.